# Buying a used camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation

Based on the discussions here earlier, I decided to get a Nikon D90. I am looking on sites for used camera. I contacted one person and here is the response I received:

> All gear is in mint condition with less than 2500 photo shutter actuations and the D90 
>   body just over 2 years old. The lens is just over a year old. Technically there is still 
>   4 years left on the Nikon warranty for the lens but apparently warranties are non
>   transferable. This is only a package deal (D90 with 55-200mm AFS lens). Price CAD $1000.

But I have no idea if the deal is worth the money I would be paying for it, since there is no warranty. Is it worth taking this path or better to stay with Nikon D5100 and buying from store that comes with all warranty for almost same price.

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @user634 - What lens?

Comment: Seems to expensive. 10 secs on eBay and I found one for $760 CDN Buy-It-Now or you can make an offer: http://cgi.ebay.ca/Nikon-D90-12-3-MP-Digital-SLR-Camera-Mint-Body-Only-/200614749388?pt=Digital_Cameras&hash=item2eb59224cc#ht_1837wt_907 - Expect a similar price on our side of the border. The lens included if not worth the difference, plus you may not even need that lens.

Comment: 55-200mm AFS lens

Comment: The question is a variation of the "which is best"-question to which the chat-room seems better suited. In six month nobody will be helped by these answers.

Comment: @Leonidas: So, where is this chat-room for discussing and how do I access that, so that I know it for the future. 
Update: I think I found it, it is called Photographic Memories, navigated from top menu right?

Comment: @user634: Yeah, that should be the one (and it is). Someone changed the layout, I'm lost (some month ago I think the chat-room-link was just on the right side somehow - so one couldn't overlook it) ;)

Comment: I have chosen to close this question, because as Leonidas states, there really isn't much in the way of useful information here, nor is there really any way to provide much useful information in this forum. It is both very subjective, and highly temporally localized, and will be rather useless in the future. I do think chat is the best place for this specific kind of question, as it is definitely more of a "discussion" than a "question". Regarding chat, most of the people who hang out in there are likely to be more than happy to discuss this kind of issue with you real-time.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to judge value is to look at multiple deals, and look for a price convergence. If you look at 10 different deals on D90 cameras from a variety of sources (i.e. eBay, Amazon, Adorama, Craigs List, and other places), and the average price comes out to be about $700-$800, then it would seem $1000 is too expensive. If the average price comes out to around $1000, then maybe it is reasonable. Just make sure that you are comparing apples to apples...wildly different "packages" with different lenses and other bundled gear will throw off any simple average, and you will have to adjust accordingly.

Ultimately, price boils down to what YOU think is reasonable when you are well-informed. I would say basing your decision on a single example from eBay is an information-anemic decision, and you could probably do better.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like a good deal to me.  You can buy a D90 used on Amazon for $600 and new 55-200mm is only $150 at Walmart.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to look at used equipment, start with reputable dealers like Adorama.  In cases of recently discontinued equipment (like the D90), you might be able to find refurbished equipment.  This might not, strictly speaking, be considered used, but you want to use this price as a high-water mark.  You'd better not pay more than this for used equipment if you can buy a refurb for the same price!

Another good source of information is ebay.  Even if you're not comfortable buying your equipment there (and there are good reasons for that), this will give you great pricing information.

Armed with a little information, you can make a better decision about whether the used price is worth the risk.